# How to replace a string

Tags: java, groovy

I have string with the values: "My name [name], my city [cIty], my country [countrY]..........".

I want to convert all the characters inside square brackets `[<value in upper or lower case>]` to `[<value in lowercase>]`.

example: [cIty] to [city]

How to do this in a efficient way with less code in java Or Groovy?

**EDIT:** I want to convert only the characters inside square brackets to lowercase not the other characters outside of square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some groovy code that should do what you want:

```
def text = "My name [name], my city [cIty], my country [countrY]."
text.findAll(/\[(.*?)\]/).each{text = text.replace(it, it.toLowerCase())}

assert text == "My name [name], my city [city], my country [country]."
```

Comment: Cool! :-)  There's also a shorter route to the answer that doesn't require you to repeatedly set the `text` variable in a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12932736/6509 :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Java code that will do the job for you:

```
String str = "My name [Name], My city [cIty], My country [countrY].";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[[^]]+\\]").matcher(str);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
   String lc = m.group().toLowerCase();
   m.appendReplacement(buf, lc);
}
m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.printf("Lowercase String is: %s%n", buf.toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Lowercase String is: My name [name], My city [city], My country [country].
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter Groovy route is:

```
def text = "My name [name], my city [cIty], my country [countrY]."
text = text.replaceAll( /\[[^\]]+\]/ ) { it.toLowerCase() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Am not familiar with Groovy, but in Java, you can do that using `string.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "My name [name], my city [cIty], my country [countrY]..........";
    System.out.println(str);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
      str = str.substring(0,matcher.start()) + matcher.group().toLowerCase() + str.substring(matcher.end());
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}

}
```